# How to write a function with arguments using promises in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Assume I have the following function:

```
Person.find({ surname: "Doe" }).only("name", "surname").run(function (err, people) {

});
```

This is what I have tried using promises:

```
Q.nfcall(Person.find.only('name', 'surname').run, {surname: 'Doe'});
```

Where should I insert arguments for the `only()` function using promises?

Thank you

Comment: What library is `Person.find` from?

Comment: orm https://www.npmjs.com/package/orm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments for `only` should go where they always went, just as well as those to `find`. It's only `run` that you want to call with a callback and get a promise out:

```
Q.nfcall(Person.find({ surname: "Doe" }).only("name", "surname").run)
.then(function(people){…}, function(err) {…});
```

But probably you'll have to use [`Q.ninvoke`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qninvokeobject-methodname-args) anyway:

```
Q.ninvoke(Person.find({ surname: "Doe" }).only("name", "surname"), "run")
.then(function(people){…}, function(err) {…});
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you're using Node.js 0.12+ or io.js, you don't need to use Q or other libraries to support promises, as they're available natively.

Second, it seems like you're using Mongoose, which support promises natively: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/harmony.html

When you call Model.find(), it returns a promise already, so you can just do:

```
var promise = Person.find({ surname: "Doe" }).only("name", "surname")
promise.then(...)
```